# Unity IMGUI - ArgumentException: Getting control's position when doing MouseDown - OnGUI Events

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I've been struggling with IMGUI (Legacy and Editor GUI system) a lot.
Problem is I cannot get my head around this Instant way and all the different events.

I built a simple example to demonstrate one of the many frustration I'm having with this system.

```
bool toggleValue;
void OnGUI()
{
    if (toggleValue = GUILayout.Toggle(toggleValue, "Toggle"))
    {
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("This is a label");
    }
}
```

Alright, so, in this very simple code, I have a native toggle that shows or not a label depending on it's state. **This works perfectly.**

Now, I'm writing a piece myself.

```
bool toggleValue;
void OnGUI()
{
    if (toggleValue = Toggle(toggleValue, "Toggle"))
    {
       EditorGUILayout.LabelField("This is a label");
    }
}

bool Toggle(bool state, string label)
{
    GUILayout.Label(label, state ? EditorStyles.boldLabel : GUIStyle.none);
    if (Event.current.type == EventType.MouseDown && Event.current.button == 0 && GUILayoutUtility.GetLastRect().Contains(Event.current.mousePosition))
        return !state;
    return state;
}
```

My goal with this one is to manually reproduce the behaviour of a toggle: My clickable label is bold when active and normal when disable. Similarly to the checkbox graphic of the native toggle. Then, if I catch a click on it's rect, I return the opposite of the state.

In my head, this is suppose to work. However, I'm aware that there's a lot going on with the OnGUI function like the events `Repaint` and `Layout` for which the layout needs to be consistent during a frame. Here the error is

> ArgumentException: Getting control 1's position in a group with only 1 controls when doing MouseDown

but often also errors like this one

> ArgumentException: GUILayout: Mismatched LayoutGroup.MouseDown

I know that these errors are when you change the content between Layout and Repaint. However I cannot find a fix for my simple control. So here is my question.

#### With the same arguments given to my function Toggle, what do I need to take care of so the toggle works?

I feel like if I have the answer to this, I might be able to understand the key to this system.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Oh my god I can't believe it. The ONLY thing I was missing was

```
Event.current.Use();
```

When the control is clicked.
That's all! Nothing about the layout being changed between Layout and Repaint or anything of the sort.

So if you've got the same problem, just consume the event when it succeeded.